# Error importing 'telepot' Telegram python module

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, telepot

Hey I need help with this python error:

```
File "bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    import telepot
File "/home/lee/venv/telegram/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 220, in <module>
    from . import helper
File "/home/lee/venv/telegram/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telepot/helper.py", line 7, in <module>
    import inspect
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 39, in <module>
    COMMENT = N_TOKENS
```

bot.py

```
import telepot


bot = telepot.Bot('<bot_token>')
print bot.getMe()

from pprint import pprint
response = bot.getUpdates()
pprint(response)
```

This error comes about as a result of importing any telegram python module. All help will be appreciated.